# Организация данных для справочника на андроид

Tags: java, android, хранение-данных

Добрый день! С недавних пор занялся изучением программирования под андроид, создавая небольшие приложения "Для себя", так как от учебы по мануалам, к сожалению, слишком быстро засыпал и терял всякий интерес.

Идеей очередного приложения стал справочник различных "объектов" планет. Соответственно, данных может быть довольно много, а их структура имеет слежующий вид(для примера):

```
Планета:`Марс`
 Животные:
  Осел
    Вес: 40кг
    Рост: 32м
  Слон
    Вес: 129кг
    Рост: 127м

 Растения:
  Одуванчик
   Тип: Астровые
   Род: Многолетние
```

...

```
Планета: Юпитер
   Животные: ...
   Растения: ...
```

и.т.п.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как организовать ввод/хранение данных, чтобы:
1) При запуске приложение уже имело введенные ранее данные
2) Была возможность добавлять данные согласно указанному выше шаблону
3) Возможность поиска по данным.

Спасибо.

Comment: хранить можно в sqlite, связи один ко многим. Там же и искать удобно будет. Ознакомьтесь на досуге с теорией баз данных

Comment: Лучшим решением хранить данные такого типа будет база данных: нативная и олдскульная SQLite или перспективная No-sql ООБД Realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранить данные можно по разному, например:
1) СУБД - Sqlite, преимуществом будет простота возможности выборки/вставки нужных данных посредством SQL запроса. СУБД упаковывает данные более менее компактно, по сравнению с другими методами.
2) Хранить данные в XML-файлы. Плюсом является переносимость данного формата между платформами, возможность в будущем реализовать без сильных изменения доставку данных не из файла, а например через сервер с RESTfull API.